# Xamarin Access Data on Other Views

Tags: android, xamarin, view, object-reference

I have a small problem releated to accessing data in other views so here is the code.

Button

```
Button button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.addExpereince);
```

Button Click

```
            button2.Click += (sender, e) =>{

            EditText addCompany = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addCompanyName);
            EditText addDate = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addDate);
            EditText addPosition = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addPosition);

            AddExpreince(1, addCompany.Text, addPosition.Text, addDate.Text);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        };
```

I want to learn, how I can solve this problem. The button and EditText are on other views, and I actually don't need them to work in the main view, I just need the code to be initialized in the MainActivity so that they can be used in the other view.

The error I'm receiving for better reference:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly but take a look on  https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.LayoutInflater/

Comment: @EvZ I think that is the problem but I'm not sure. I'm a bit confused about this issue.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It is very hard to understand your question / problem. You can use LayoutInflator to init a view from any AXML.

Comment: `"button and EditText are on other views"` Other view? Do you mean other Activity or Fragment or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**You should use `SetContentView()` first**, as per the document :

> Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

If you didn't add a layout to your `Activity` first, **your `Activity` is basically an empty window**. As a result, when you use `FindViewById` method you will get a `NullReferenceException` exception.

## Solution :

Modify your code like this :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    // Get our button from the layout resource,
    // and attach an event to it
    Button button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.addExpereince);

    EditText addCompany = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addCompanyName);
    EditText addDate = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addDate);
    EditText addPosition = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.addPosition);

    button2.Click += (sender, e) => 
    {
        AddExpreince(1, addCompany.Text, addPosition.Text, addDate.Text);
    };
}
```